# Add a timeout to "setInterval()"?

Tags: javascript

I have a setInterval function like below on a Divbox so if **I leave a divbox**, this **setInterval is triggered**:

```
setInterval("playthis()", 1000);
```

**What I want it to do:** If I leave the divbox and lets say within the next 2 second rehover it, the setInterval should **not** triggered.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use cousins `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` to set a function callback that invokes your `setInterval` only after 2 uninterrupted seconds:

```
var handle = null;

function yourDivboxLeaveHandler() {
   handle = setTimeout(startPlay, 2000);
}

function yourDivboxHoverHandler() {
   if (handle !== null) {
       clearTimeout(handle);
       handle = null;
   }
}

function startPlay() {
   setInterval(playthis, 1000); // use function references please, not eval
   handle = null;
}
```

You will want much better variable/function names than this though.

Comment: Alternatively use anonymous functions and dispense with the names altogether.

Comment: @Vilx: An alteration unrelated to the crux of the issue.

Comment: Hence written in a comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just make some creative use of `clearInterval()`.

In other words, no, such a feature doesn't come out-of-the-box, but you can build it yourself by calling `clearInterval()` if the mouse re-enters the divbox before the interval is triggered.

For example:

```
var divBox = document.getElementById('MyDivBox');
var TimeoutHandle = null;

divBox.onmouseover = function()
{
    if ( TimeoutHandle != null )
    {
        clearTimeout(TimeoutHandle);
    }
}

divBox.onmouseout = function()
{
    TimeoutHandle = setTimeout(function()
    {
        TimeoutHandle = null;
        setInterval(playthis, 1000);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: I do that but I want this timeout on it

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Ahh, you know, just trying to be the first to post an answer. :)

Comment: @Vilx: Tut tut... it's not a race!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - It is, if you're after the rep. ;)

Comment: @Vilx: But that's not we're here for!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - No, but it's entertaining anyway. :) It's like a challenge - will you manage to get the accepted answer? Or at least some upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

First of all is a bad practice to have the code evalued in a setInterval so you should avid double quotes. Then you can clear the interval like this:

```
 var int = setInterval(playthis, 1000);
 clearInterval(int)
```